# Mercurial equivalent for Git's squash merge

Tags: git, merge, mercurial, branching-and-merging

I created a named branch for a small feature, now I'd like to merge it to the default branch but not push the feature branch.

In git, I could do `git merge --squash my-feature`. What's the equivalent in Mercurial or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Git "squash merge" is not a merge at all.  It uses the merge *machinery* to copy the effect of a bunch of other commits, and the merge-base-finding machinery to determine which diff to apply, but then it just applies those changes directly as a new, independent commit:

```
...--o--B--o--@    <-- you-are-here
         \
          Q--R--S   <-- stuff-you-want-to-squash
```

Git now effectively does `git diff B S | git apply -3`.

Mercurial doesn't have quite that, but since this *copies* the effect of commits `Q-R-S` and adds them as a new commit after `@`, you can use `hg rebase`.  See the `--keep` option if you want to keep the original `Q-R-S` (or however many commits there are), and the `--collapse` option to get the squashing effect.

Comment: Full command
`hg rebase --keep --collapse -s commit_hash-of_first_commit_in_my_feature_branch -d default`

Further reading: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/27/move-unpushed-changes/